# Is there any method to flatten the data in Json dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, json-flattener

I have a Json file which I then converted to a Json dataFrame. and that Json dataFrame consisting of a lot of columns but now, I have to flatten that Json dataFrame, which should contain only the specific columns. so, I am here to ask, is there any method in Python to solve this problem?

I expect the output should contain only certain columns in its flattened form

I had the Json file which I converted to dataframe. Now, the problem is that I have to flatten the data per item array as needed, so I have to choose only few columns from that large file. So, my question is, is there any method to easily flatten those columns. I don't want to put every array containing those columns, I just want to use the name of that column only once and it will fetch that columns and its values from the dataframe and then flatten it. So, please suggest me an efficient way to do this.